# How to compare two properties of the same Object using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class

```
class MyClass
{
    public int ActualAge {get;set;}
    public int ReportedAge{get;set;}
}
```

I have a populated collection of the above class as below

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>
{ 
    new MyClass { ActualAge= 10, ReportedAge =10}, 
    new MyClass { ActualAge= 10, ReportedAge =30} , 
    new MyClass { ActualAge= 20, ReportedAge =20}, 
    new MyClass { ActualAge= 10, ReportedAge = 90}
};
```

Now the challenge is if

```
AcutalAge == ReportedAge
```

then (lets assume there is another variable)

```
private List<int> Age
```

Age variable should be equal to collection of ActualAge property and if not then Age variable should be equal to the collection of ActualAge/ReportedAge.

I'm wondering how can I achieve this by using LINQ in C#.

Comment: You meant `ReportedAge` instead of `ReportedHeight` right ?

Comment: Yeah sorry for that I edited it.

Comment: Can you give us some sample inputs and expected outputs ?

Comment: What's your attempt? I'm sure you can make a start on this, it's not particularly challenging. it's simply a `Select()` with an if statement within the lambda you pass.

Comment: It sounds like you always want the ActualAge of each item, regardless of whether it's equal to ReportedAge.

Comment: Age
----
10
12/13
40
15/18
30
22/24
30

Comment: Linq is good performance-wise.

Comment: So Age is not an integer List? 10 12/13 40 15/18

Comment: @user2913184 What gives you that impression? If anything, LINQ is slightly slower than writing proper procedural code. LINQ is just cleaner to read and write.

Comment: _"Linq is good performance-wise"_ - that's not necessarily true and ignores my first question.

Comment: Where ActualAge and ReportedAge are equal I display  only the ActualAge but where they are not I dispplay ActualAge/ReportedHeight under the Age field.

Comment: Age list can be List<string>?

Comment: @user2913184 Then make an attempt. Start with writing a select that simply returns `ActualAge`. Then add an `if` block. SO isn't a coding service, and this question is something you should be able to figure out after reading a tutorial or two about LINQ.

Comment: @Rob the thing is I know how to write a select statement using Linq but when u say add an if block , what will u write inside the if statement?

Comment: @user2913184 You would write pretty much exactly what you've described.. If actual age = reported age then return actual age otherwise return actual age / reported age

Answer (score 3):

If `Age` is declared as `List<string>`
You can use following code to populate this list

```
List<string> Age
Age = myClassList.Select(x => x.ReportedAge == x.ActualAge ?
                                          x.ReportedAge.ToString() :
                                          string.Format("{0}/{1}", x.ReportedAge, x.ActualAge)).ToList()
```

So your list will contains `10`, `12/13`, `40`, `15/18`

Answer (score 2):

You want to perform a "Select" on `myClassList`, to map the desired state of each item into your resultant `Age` list.  In order to display only the `ActualAge` when the two are equal, use a conditional statement within your `Select`:

```
List<string> Age = myClassList.Select(i =>
                                      i.ActualAge == i.ReportedAge
                                         ? i.ActualAge.ToString()
                                         : String.Format("{0}/{1}",
                                             i.ActualAge,
                                             i.ReportedAge)
                    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`IList<string> Age = myClassList.Select(x => x.ActualAge == x.ReportedAge ? x.ActualAge + "/" + x.ReportedAge : x.ActualAge.ToString()).ToList()`